# Problems with launching via XPC. XPC error : Connection interrupted

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to run my cocoa application from root with Objective-c, when I run it very first time after starting Xcode it runs properly, but as a stop the application and run again it show me error -
"Problems with launching via XPC. XPC error : Connection interrupted" , though I haven't use XPC in my project.

I am using Xcode version 11.1

Error Details - 
"Details

Could not launch “test2”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3

### Failure Reason: Problems with launching via XPC. XPC error : Connection interrupted

Problems with launching via XPC. XPC error : Connection interrupted
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain

### Code: 3

"